# What does "duplicate symbol _heating_unit in BangBangControlTest.o and BangBangControl.o" mean?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

Im receiving this error when trying to compile my code.

`$ g++ -o BangBangControlTest BangBangControl.o BangBangControlTest.o
ld: duplicate symbol _heating_unit in BangBangControlTest.o and BangBangControl.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

I am new to C++ and can't find out what is wrong. I've searched through many tutorials and looked at similar error messages received by other stack users. Here are my classes.
"BangBangControlTest.cpp"

```
// Test function
#include <iostream>
#include "BangBangControl.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
  BangBangControl control(50, true, 75);

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
std::cout << "Temp = " << control.update() << endl;
}

return 0;

}
```

"BangBangControl.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BangBangControl.h"
using namespace std;

BangBangControl::BangBangControl(int temp, bool isOn, int initialTemp){
  heating_unit = HeatingUnit(isOn, initialTemp);
  temp_to_maintain = temp;
}

void BangBangControl::setTemp(int temp){temp_to_maintain = temp;}
int BangBangControl::getTemp(){return temp_to_maintain;}
int BangBangControl::update(){
  int b=heating_unit.tick();
  if (b  > temp_to_maintain + 2) heating_unit.turnOff();  if (b  < temp_to_maintain - 2) heating_unit.turnOn();
  return b;
}
```

"BangBangControl.h"

```
// BangBangControl header
#include <iostream>
#include "HeatingUnit.h"
using namespace std;

HeatingUnit heating_unit;
int temp_to_maintain;

class BangBangControl{

 public:
   BangBangControl(int, bool, int);
    void setTemp(int);
    int getTemp();
    int update();
 };
```

"HeatingUnit.cpp"

```
// HeatingUnit class implementation

#include <iostream>
#include "HeatingUnit.h"

using namespace std;

HeatingUnit::HeatingUnit(bool a, int b){
  isOn = a;
  temp = b;
}

void HeatingUnit::turnOn(){isOn = true;}

void HeatingUnit::turnOff(){isOn = false;}

int HeatingUnit::tick(){
  if(isOn && temp <= 100){
    return ++temp;

}
  else if((!isOn) && temp >= 0){
    return --temp;
  }
  else{
    return temp;
  }
}
```

"HeatingUnit.h"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class HeatingUnit{
  public:
    bool isOn;
    int temp;

    HeatingUnit();
    HeatingUnit(bool, int);
    void turnOn();
    void turnOff();
    int tick();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see that `HeatingUnit heating_unit;` in your header file?  You need to put `extern` in front of it, and copy the original version without the extern to the .cpp file, optionally specifying an initial value there.

You can read more about this here: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c)